# Event bubbling issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

I am using event bubbling like below to resize `h3` tagged text at mouse hover, and back to original size when mouse is not hovering on text. But it doesn't work.

```
$('body').hover(function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('h3')) {
        $(event.target).hover(function () {
            $(this).css("font-size", "40px");
        },
        function () {
            $(this).css("font-size", "40px");
        });
    }
});
```

I am newbie.So there might be a stupid mistake.Please point out.
Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to apply the event to the `h3` element itself. Try this:

```
$("h3").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("font-size", "40px");
},
function() {
     $(this).css("font-size", "20px");
});
```

Also, it would be better to use CSS classes to amend the sizing of the font as it is a better separation of concerns:

```
$("h3").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("big-text");
},
function() {
     $(this).removeClass("big-text");
});

// CSS
h3 { font-size: 12px; }
.big-text { font-size: 40px; }
```

**UPDATE**

As the `h3` elements are dynamically loaded you need to use `on` with a delegate. Try this:

```
$("body").on("hover", "h3", function(e) {
    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
       $(this).css("font-size", "40px");
    }
    else { // mouseleave
        $(this).css("font-size", "20px"); 
    }
});
```

I have used `body` as the main selector here, but you should use the closest element to the `h3` elements which is available on page load.

Comment: right.but my requirement is different.i have some buttons on the page,that use the ajax call to loading other files as per the click.so text return by those file also contains h3 tagged text.so i need to apply hovering on those as well.so that i was using above procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'h3', function(event) {
       $(this).css("font-size", "40px");
})

$(document).on('mouseleave', 'h3', function(event) {
       $(this).css("font-size", "20px");
})
```

or:

```
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
       $(this).addClass('aClass')
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
       $(this).removeClass('aClass')
}, 'h3')
```